# Why is socket.remoteAddress undefined on 'end' event?

Tags: sockets, node.js

I have a simple TCP server as follows:

```
var net = require('net');
var PORT = 6346;

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {

    socket.on('connect', function() {
        console.log('Client connected: ' + socket.remoteAddress);
        socket.write('Welcome to the server!\r\n');
    });

    socket.on('end', function() {
        console.log('Client disconnected: ' + socket.remoteAddress);
    });

    socket.on('error', function() {
        console.log('Client error: ' + socket.remoteAddress);
    });

    socket.on('timeout', function() {
        console.log('Client timed out:' + socket.remoteAddress);
    });


}).listen(PORT);
```

When I connect to the server I see the expected `Client connected: 127.0.0.1` but when I disconnect I see `Client disconnected: undefined`. Why is socket.remoteAddress undefined and how can I log the IP of the client upon disconnect?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that after the socket is disconnected, certain properties (such as `remoteAddress`) are no longer available!

You can get around this by wrapping socket with your own object, or by keeping track of that remote address somewhere else upon connect.  (Woot for closures.)

Comment: I suspected that was the problem. I just didn't see that in the documentation. I suppose I can add a property in the Connect event like this `socket.ip = socket.remoteAddress;` right?

Comment: @styfle, Absolutely.  I think I have done this in my own applications at one point.  I'm generally wary of modifying and object I didn't create though, for future compatibility if nothing else.  I would recommend setting a variable in your closure instead.

Comment: @styfle, Within your `function (socket) {}`, just do a `var remoteAddress = socket.remoteAddress`.

Answer (score 2):

The remoteAddress property will be around even after disconnect once https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/8c38b07252d86f4eef91344f8df4f0c3e38bca35 is in a stable version of Node.js. io.js will have it in the next release: https://github.com/iojs/io.js/issues/1157

Comment: Thanks for posting both the Node.js and io.js commits. It's sad that these two communities fork.

Answer (score 0):

While trying to debug 504 errors from certain servers, I found that changing this code

```
request(url, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
        callback(error);
    } else {
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            callback(null, body);
        } else {
            // response.connection.remoteAddress is undefined here
            callback(new Error("Non status 200: " + response.statusCode + " received from " + response.connection.remoteAddress + " when requesting " + url));
        }
    }
});
```

to this code

```
request(url, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
        callback(error);
    } else {
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            callback(null, body);
        } else {
            // response.connection.remoteAddress is now magically set somehow
            callback(new Error("Non status 200: " + response.statusCode + " received from " + response.connection.remoteAddress + " when requesting " + url));
        }
    }
}).on('response', function(response) {
    // This next line is very important.  It seems to make the remoteAddress variable stay in the socket so we can read it.
    let remoteAddress = response.connection.remoteAddress;
});
```

seemed to work.  I have no idea why accessing the remoteAddress variable in the response handler makes it stick around for reading.